# Can I define a Repository for an Abstract Class in spring-data-couchbase?

Tags: spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Can I define a Repository for an Abstract Class in spring-data-couchbase?
And if not, is there any plan to add this capability in the future? It would be really useful to my team...

To elaborate a little on my use case...

(In Spring-boot 2.1.11.RELEASE and spring-data-couchbase 3.2.25.RELEASE) 
Currently if I define a spring-data-couchbase `CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository` for an abstract class, the only method I've found that returns any results is `findById()`, and as far as I can tell, that only works because there's a bug in the library that forgets to include the `_class = 'fully.qualified.ClassName'` where-clause when generating the `findById()` query.

In fact, in Jackson, there's already an annotation available for defining how to include the java class name in the serialized JSON - `@JsonTypeInfo`, `@JsonSubTypes`, and `@JsonTypeName`. Would it be possible for spring-data-couchbase to leverage those annotations or create something similar of their own?

Our use case is that we are storing several closely related, but slightly different document types in the same Couchbase bucket. Sometimes we want to run queries against a specific sub-type, but most of the time, we'd like to run queries against all the sub-types. Of course we can always use custom N1QL queries via the couchbase bucket, but it would be pretty cool if spring-data-couchbase understood Jackson annotations, since Spring already uses them to render responses in the Controllers. It seems like a pretty useful potential feature for spring-data-couchbase, if it's not a feature already...

Here's an illustration of what we'd like via code:

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "javaClass")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bird.class, name = "Bird"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Cat")
})
public abstract class Creature implements Serializable {
    protected static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @Id
    protected String id;
    protected Integer height;
    protected Classification classification;
}
```

```
@Data
@Document
@JsonTypeName("Bird")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Bird extends Creature {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    private Integer wingspan;
}
```

```
@Data
@Document
@JsonTypeName("Cat")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Cat extends Creature {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    private Integer numLives;
}
```

And then to be able to define repositories like this:

```
@Repository
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "creature")
public interface CreatureRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<Creature, String> {
    Optional<Creature> findByHeight(Integer height);
    Optional<Creature> findByClassification_Genus(String genus);
}
```

```
@Repository
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "cat")
public interface CatRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<Cat, String> {
    Optional<Cat> findByHeight(Integer height);
    Optional<Cat> findByNumLives(Integer numLives);
}
```